# How do you find the interval of convergence for the series $f(x)=\sin(2x)$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I know that $$\sin(2x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty{(-1)^n\frac{2^{2n+1}x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}}$$

I did the ratio test and came up with the

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\frac{-4x^2}{2(n+1)(2n+3)}}$$

Comment: Well, what is that limit?

Answer (score 5):

Using ratio test provides us with the limit that you've given above: $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\left| \frac{-4x^2}{2(n+1)(2n+3)}\right|}$$

Simplifying this to $$2x^2\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\frac{1}{(n+1)(2n+3)}}.$$  Thus, we need only find the limit involving $n$.  Since the bottom increases without bound, we see that this limit is 0.  Thus, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\left| \frac{-4x^2}{2(n+1)(2n+3)}\right|}=0$.  The ratio test says that given the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty{a_n}$, if $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|}<1$, then it converges absolutely.  Thus, the interval of convergence is $(-\infty,\infty)$ since the limit convergence independently of our choice of $x$.